# My Account Page does not created after installing Woo-commerce Plugin on my wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have installed Woo-commerce Plugin in my WordPress E-commerce site but "My Account" Page does not created on page section. Please give me suggestion how i will get this page to working with this page functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign My Account Page from Woo Commerce settings to any of your page in Wordpress.

Woo Commerce => Settings => Account